# Verify an image is a zoomed version of actual image through python script

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to find out a solution through python for a way to verify if I passed two images one is actual and another is the zoomed one of the actual one.I need to get as it is the zoomed version of the actual image.If any one having any suggestions please comment I googled a lot but I cannot able to find a proper solution on it.

Comment: Search for `image resize invariant features` in google and you will get appropriate results. As far as OpenCV is concerned, You can use SIFT which comes under opencv_contrib

Comment: Check **image pyramids** [HERE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dff/tutorial_py_pyramids.html)

Comment: Thanks ZdaR and Jeru Luke for the qucik reply,if you can give some snippet of code where i can pass path of two images actual and zoomed gives the desired output it will be some more helpful.Tks

Comment: Resize the bigger image to the size of smaller image and then compare the two images. As for code, try and update the question to show what you tried and where you  are finding difficulty. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Vivek,Say Image1 is my actual image and Image2 is the zoomed one of Image1,When I zoomed an image, actually the middle portion of the Image1 is getting zoomed and some portions of Image1 will be missed out in Image2 once it is fully zoomed.Image2 now carries almost the middle zoomed portion of the Image1 and this is what I need to verify.

Comment: scale invariant features like SIFT or SURF typically are very well suited for such a task.

Comment: Agree with @Micka What you need is image registration techniques. SIFT will work quiet well in those cases. Take a look at OpenSURF and OpenCV implementation.

Comment: Thanks will check on the same and revert back.